In hyperbolic geometry, people confuse the difference between non-intersecting lines and parallel?
In hyperbolic geometry, non-intersecting lines are not necessarily equidistant. And parallel are definitely equidistant. So non-intersecting lines are not necessarily parallel. In plane geometry, non-intersecting lines are equidistant, so they are also parallel. There is no difference between the two. So, in hyperbolic geometry, people confuse the difference between non-intersecting lines and parallel. Is there anything wrong here?

I'm afraid you're the one confusing notions. At the foundational level, parallelism is a (non-)incidence property, defined as simply as possible as non-intersecting-ness, so that the term has meaning even before metric properties are introduced. Moreover, in hyperbolic geometry, "equidistant curves" are in fact never lines. (Consider, say, the Poincaré disk model: lines are either diameters of, or arcs of circles orthogonal to the boundary of, the Disk. An "equidistant curve" for a given line happens to be any non-line circular arc that shares both ("ideal") endpoints with the line.)

@Blue  I mean that the distance between the so-called parallel lines in hyperbolic geometry is not constant, so although they do not intersect, they are not parallel. So it should be said that there are no parallel lines in hyperbolic geometry.

You invented your own terminology (assigining nonstandard meaning to the words "line" and "parallel") which is inconsistent with the standard one. Then you are claiming that people who are not using your terminology are making a mistake. There is no real math question here.

@MoisheKohan: I've realized that OP is someone who posted a number of years ago with a similarly-frustrating attitude about notions in spherical geometry. See, for instance, this old (deleted) question by OP, and the interactions in the comments. (In comments to this old answer of mine, I noted my suspicion that OP was also active here as E.wei and z.qmpx.) My recommendation is: Do not engage.

@MoisheKohan  Sorry, it's my language problem.
Are there straight lines in hyperbolic geometry? Are there parallel in hyperbolic geometry? If there are parallel, are they equidistant? If you say there are parallel, but they are not equidistant. Then my doubt exists.

@Blue: Agree...
